# how to upload a file using curl command to a webserver?

Tags: linux, curl

I have a file t.txt which contains "Test--lines". I want to upload it on the webserver.

I am using curl -F "file=@/tmp/t.txt;filename=t.txt" /path/of/web/server/where/I/want/to/upload/file/

but I am getting "The requested URL is was not found on this server" error. But there is the path available on the server.

Comment: How do I check service to transfer a file and receive a file are enable on linux server?

Comment: No, that command line will get:

`curl: (3) <url> malformed`

Answer (score 0):

You need a CGI program running on the web server that is able to receive uploads. Then you curl to that program's url. Also, it would be a disaster to have anybody able to upload whatever they want without any kind of login.

Maybe it would be easier to upload files using scp?

Comment: I dont want to use scp... /path/of/web/server/where/I/want/to/upload/file/ is http://ip_address/directory .... so when ever I want to upload using it will asking me for password n I dont knwo the password of root

Comment: If web server admin wanted you to be able to upload files, she has given you username and password to use for uploading. Most likely they work with scp. It's the same user/password you use to logon with ssh/putty. How do you make web pages to the server?